# JOIN perform improve with pivoted data

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server query below - PIVOT tables has large amounts of data. The SQL works perfectly and uses the correct indexes, but it takes a long time. I'm just checking to see if there is anything I could do better.

```
DECLARE @DFLId VARCHAR(13) = '25'

SELECT                    
    COALESCE(MM.CPD,MM1.CPD,Mlk.CPD,N.CPD) CPD,
    COALESCE(MM.MANbr,MM1.MANbr,Mlk.MANbr,N.MANbr) MANbr,
    COALESCE(MM.PC,MM1.PC,Mlk.PC,M.PC) PC,
    A.*
FROM 
    (SELECT A.* 
     FROM dbo.tblA A 
     WHERE A.DFLId = @DFLId) B  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MID, CPD, PC, MANbr 
     FROM dbo.tblpivot WITH(INDEX(idx_tblpivot_PC_MId)) 
     WHERE LEFT(MANbr, 1) != 'L') MM  ON B.CPD = MM.PC AND B.MID = MM.MID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MID, CPD, PC, MANbr 
     FROM dbo.tblpivot WITH(INDEX(idx_tblpivot_PC_MId)) 
     WHERE LEFT(MANbr, 1) = 'L') MM1 ON B.PC = MM1.PC AND B.MId = MM1.MId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MID, CPD, PC, MANbr 
     FROM dbo.tblpivot WITH(INDEX(idx_tblpivot_MT)) 
     WHERE MT IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')) Mlk ON B.MId = Mlk.MId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MID, CPD, PC, MANbr 
     FROM dbo.tblpivot WITH(INDEX(idx_tblpivot_MT)) 
     WHERE MT = 'DB') N ON (B.PC = N.PC)
```

Comment: . . Why would you put a Postgres tag on a SQL Server question?  Someone with your reputation should know about tagging the correct database.  I would also suggest that you provide sample data and desired results and explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: Gosh sorry, was trying to get some kind of response from experts :(

Comment: Basically i'm looking for data from the pivot merged into main tblA. I can either do left outer with main tblA along with filters or union all the pivot tbl queries and then join to main tblA.. i guess it's same. I don't want to use OR condition and do single sql to get pivot tbl data because indexes are going to be wasted that way. I'm trying to find some alternatives for left outer join.. subquery won't give columns to the main tblA

Comment: As always: Please submit execution graph - it is possible that indices are missing. Also  - how much data? And why is the ID a STRING - that is as inefficient as it gets. And I am not sure LEFT(MANbr,1) = 'L'  is using an index, compared to "LIKE 'MANbr%'" which DOES use an index.

Comment: I'll try to get the execution plan but there is no missing indexes at all.. I took care of that way ahead. If it's a index issue, i would have probably sorted by now.

Comment: ID is varchar in the table by design, i can change but i'm not sure if that would make a big impact. plus there is a index on MANbr i'll change my indexes to below  WITH(INDEX(idx_tblpivot_PC_MId, idx_tblpivot_MANbr))